# nginx rewrite to views folder

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How do I rewrite the following?  I have my html views in my views/dist folder but don't want that folder in the url.

domainname/home/index.html -> domainname/views/dist/home/index.html

domainname/user/login.html -> domainname/views/dist/user/login.html

Comment: Have you considered changing the `root` to include `/views/dist` rather than rewriting the URI?

Comment: No, because I have js and css in the root folder.